# not all paths have value while redicting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using mvc4

i have a method in my controller. i want this method to redict the use to another method in another controller. i tried this

```
public ActionResult Building(int buildingID) {
    if((buildingID == 0) || (buildingID<0))
        return HttpNotFound();
    else
        RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Building", action = "details?id=" + buildingID });
}
```

but i got this exception

```
not all paths have value
```

what am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre `else` statement doesn't return an `ActionResult`

This `RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Building", action = "details?id=" + buildingID });` does not return a value.  If `RedirectToRoute` returns an `ActionResult` you can just add the `return` keyword in front of it to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **return** in the else statement:

```
return RedirectToRoute(new 
{ 
    controller = "Building", 
    action = "details", 
    id = buildingID 
});
```

Also notice that I am passing the `id` as part of the anonymous object instead of hardcoding it as some query string parameter to the action name.

Comment: You deserve another +1 for the code improvement. Can't give you two +1s though.

Comment: No, you can't have that error if all paths of your method return a value.

Comment: No, this is not wrong. Make sure you have a `return` statement in your else condition. Did you read my answer carefully? `return RedirectToRoute`, not `RedirectToRoute` as you have in your code.

Comment: thank you very much, please accept my apology cos i didnt select your ansewr, but that guy answer me first, i always appreciate your help and efforts with me. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

```
return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Building", action = "details?id=" + buildingID });
```

Also, I think you can use, but I need to double check

```
return RedirectToAction("details", "Building", new { id = buildingID  });
```

Also, you could change this line (just to clean up the code)...

```
if((buildingID == 0) || (buildingID<0))
```

To..

```
if(buildingID < 1)
```